# Adding Edit button to each row in the table using $.each JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, loops, button

I am trying to add "Edit" button to each row of data in the table which is created using a $.each loop in JQuery. I can see the data but no buttons beside them. HELP?

Here is what I am doing:

```
$.each(data, function (key, item) {
    // Add a list item for the product.
    $("#table1").append("<tr><td>" + item.id + "</td><td>" + item.name + "</td> <td>" + item.type + "</td> <td>" + item.weight + "</td> <td>" + item.birthday + "</td> <td>" + item.hasHorns + "</td><td><input class='edit' type='submit' value='EDIT'/> </td></tr>");
});
```

Thank you

Comment: What does it say when you view the source at the end of a row? Your markup is valid. [http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/ucf9Lvb4/](http://jsfiddle.net/tomanow/ucf9Lvb4/)

Comment: works fine for me also http://jsfiddle.net/05mqwfjb/

Comment: Hi @user2094169 - Thank you for providing code with your question. However, your question is still missing what results you're seeing. If you could add: the results you're seeing, what your data looks like, and any other pertinent data, that would be very helpful to getting your question answered.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your time. I cannot add pictures because I need 10 reputation to do so. So here is what i get.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for your time. I cannot add pictures because I need 10 reputation to do so and I just have 9.However, let me describe to you what i get. I get all the table row with data but at the end of line in $("#table1").append I have added a td to add a button for each row. That button is not visible, or should I say its not being rendered. I dont see buttons at all, only data from Item.id, Item.Name etc. Hope that helps. Thank you